Printing 3D shape to console
I've learned how to print 2D shapes with " * " symbols by using for loops, thanks to a project I've been working on but I wanted to level up a bit. I want to create 3D shapes by using and combining 2D shapes.
For example, its easy to print a 2D square but I want to print a 3D cube. Same with rectangular prisms. I can print rectangles but can't print rectangular prisms.
I know its not quite possible to print 3D things on a 2D terminal but it can at least look like its 3D by just adding some other shapes to a 2D shape.
I couldn't find any solutions or ideas on how to print these things. It looks like it can be solved by some basic for loops but no matter what I tried, it didn't work.
My idea is here:
Printing a square on the screen, then putting 2 different parallelograms on the side and the top so that it looks like its a 3D cube.
Same idea goes for rectangular prisms. First print a rectangle, then print 2 different parallelograms on the side and the top of it so it looks like its 3D.
First I tried the rectangular prism. I can't print another parallelogram on the side that has the same lenght as the parallelogram on the top and the same height as the rectangle.
If I can learn how to print this one, I'll try printing other 3D shapes that I can think of.
I could only make it this far and I can't go further. What I've tried is here:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Empty {

public static void rectangle() {
         int a = 5;
     int b = 8;
      for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
         if (i == 0) continue;
          for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
             if (j == 0 || j == (b - 1) || i == (a - 1)) {
                 System.out.print(" * ");
             } else {
                 System.out.print("   ");
             }
         }
         System.out.println();
     }
 }
  public static void parallelogram() {
     int i, j, k;
     int height = 5;
     int width = 8;
      for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < height - i - 1; j++) {
             System.out.print("   ");
         }
         for (k = 0; k < width; k++) {
             if (i == 0 || i == height - 1 || k == 0 || k == width - 1) {
                 System.out.print(" * ");
             } else {
                 System.out.print("   ");
             }
         }
         System.out.println();
     }
 }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    parallelogram();
     rectangle();
 }


}

This code block provides a shape that contains a parallelogram and a rectangle under it. What Im trying to make is connect right-top corner of the paralellogram and the right-bottom corner of the rectangle by using " * " symbols.
Its simply adding another parallelogram. Here's the output:
             *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 
          *                    * 
       *                    * 
    *                    * 
 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 
 *                    * 
 *                    * 
 *                    * 
 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 

What I want is here:


If you naively print the right part, it would interfere with the other part you are printing so you would either need to print it together/line by line which would be annoying to deal with (you'd need to handle both shapes together and have many edge cases) or you first store all the data in a char[][] (or similar) and then print that to the console which allows you to incrementally write to parts to the array and jump around easily.

@dan1st This one was just an example on what I am actually doing. Would it still work with scanners and getters/setters?
Can you recommend any vids about learning storing data in a char? I have never known something like that.

Yes, it doesn't stop you from using getters/setters or Scanner. It just means storing/buffering what you want to print and printing all at once when you are finished "drawing".

I just generated the box.  I created an image of the console result.

I created a two-dimensional char array and built the box row by row.  When I finished creating the char array, I "printed" it on a StringBuilder.
To run the Java application, you set the width, height, and depth of the box.
Here's the complete runnable code.
public class ThreeDShapes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(createCube(8, 5, 8));
    }

    public static String createCube(int width, int height, int depth) {
        int maxWidth = width + depth - 1;
        int maxHeight = height + depth - 1;
        char[][] ch = new char[maxHeight][maxWidth];
        char asterisk = '*';
//      return Arrays.deepToString(ch);

        // create first row
        int row = 0;
        int start = maxWidth - width;
        addEdgeLine(ch, start, width, row, asterisk);

        // create next rows
        int end = start + width - 2;
        start--;
        for (row = 1; row <= depth - 2; row++) {
            ch[row][start--] = asterisk;
            ch[row][end--] = asterisk;
        }

        // create top of box;
        row = depth - 1;
        addEdgeLine(ch, 0, width, row, asterisk);

        // create next rows
        start = 0;
        end = width - 1;
        for (row = depth; row < (maxHeight - 1); row++) {
            ch[row][start] = asterisk;
            ch[row][end] = asterisk;
        }

        // create other side
        int col = maxWidth - 1;
        for (row = 1; row <= (height - 1); row++) {
            ch[row][col] = asterisk;
        }
        col--;
        for (row = height; row < maxHeight; row++) {
            ch[row][col--] = asterisk;
        }

        // create bottom of box
        row = maxHeight - 1;
        addEdgeLine(ch, 0, width, row, asterisk);

        return printCharArray(ch, maxWidth, maxHeight);
    }

    private static void addEdgeLine(char[][] ch, int start, int width, int row,
            char asterisk) {
        for (int col = start; col < (width + start); col++) {
            ch[row][col] = asterisk;
        }
    }

    private static String printCharArray(char[][] ch, int maxWidth,
            int maxHeight) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int row = 0; row < maxHeight; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < maxWidth; col++) {
                builder.append(ch[row][col]);
                if (col < (maxWidth - 1)) {
                    builder.append("   ");
                }
            }
            builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
            if (row < (maxHeight - 1)) {
                builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

}


Thats exactly what I was looking for but Im a novice student so I dont really understand most of the things in this code block. Im not asking for an explanation, since it would be a very long one but if theres a way to help me understand what actually happens with this code, I would appreciate it.

@Completely Zero: The only "trick" is writing the char array to the StringBuilder.  That's where I add the row spacing and the column double line separator.  The rest is moving asterisks to various positions.  The commented line that prints the char array can be placed anywhere you want to see intermediate results.
